# ByRef not carrying Through IN vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object

The one calls form 2 as a dialog, and passed by ref a "pointer" to the base class(abstract).
//Form 1 calling form two. And Passing a ref object

```
Dim CreateForm As New frmCreate(Robot)
```

//Second Forms Overloaded New

```
Public Sub New(ByRef Robot As cRobot)
    InitializeComponent()
    thisRobot = Robot
End Sub

Select Case (cbType.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            lblOther.Text = "Bullet Proof Value"
            Dim SecRobot = New cSecurityRobot
            SecRobot.Name = txtName.Text
            SecRobot.Temperature = nudTemp.Value
            SecRobot.Threshold = nudThreshold.Value
            SecRobot.BulletproofValue = nudOther.Value
            thisRobot = SecRobot
        Case 1
            lblOther.Text = "Special Moves"
            Dim SpRobot = New cSportsRobot
            SpRobot.Name = txtName.Text
            SpRobot.Temperature = nudTemp.Value
            SpRobot.Threshold = nudThreshold.Value
            SpRobot.SpecialMoves = nudOther.Value
            thisRobot = SpRobot
        Case 2
            lblOther.Text = "Domestic Skills"
            Dim SerRobot = New cServiceRobot
            lblOther.Text = "Domestic Skills"
            SerRobot.Name = txtName.Text
            SerRobot.Temperature = nudTemp.Value
            SerRobot.Threshold = nudThreshold.Value
            SerRobot.DomesticSkills = nudOther.Value
            thisRobot = SerRobot
        Case Else
            lblOther.Text = "Bullet Proof Value"
            Dim SecRobot = New cSecurityRobot
            SecRobot.Name = txtName.Text
            SecRobot.Temperature = nudTemp.Value
            SecRobot.Threshold = nudThreshold.Value
            SecRobot.BulletproofValue = nudOther.Value
            thisRobot = SecRobot
    End Select
```

Form 2 assigns some values and terminates, but there is always a NULL Exception occurring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef Robot As cRobot)
    InitializeComponent()
    thisRobot = Robot '<-- Problem is here
End Sub
```

On the line indicated above, you are making a *copy* of the reference, and so the ByRef no longer helps you.

Thinking about how to get around this problem, you might be able to do it by nesting the Robot inside another class:

```
Public Class RobotContainer
     Public Property Robot As Robot
End Class
```

Pass a RobotContainer instance to your constructor in the normal (ByVal) way and keep a reference to that entire object in your class. Now, both your frmCreate type and the calling code have a reference to the *same object*.  When you update the Robot property on that object, it will be updated for both locations.

But really, this whole design doesn't smell right. Normally I would suggest a method that return the created robot, rather than trying to assign it to an outside location directly, but I understand that working with Windows Forms controls this may not be option. To suggest a better solution we'd need to see a lot more of your code.

---

Hmm... looking back at this I wanted to do something to make the RobotContainer more useful:

```
Public Class ReferenceContainer(Of T)
    Public Property Item As T
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Joel - I changed strategies.

Instead of passing to the form's New i overloaded the OnshowDialog and passed ByRef there, and well that solved the problem(but i don't like it).

But like i said - that solved the problem, so enough complaining from me.

Thanks again for all your time.

Aiden

Comment: Ps i really like your approach

Answer (score 2):

No, the "ByRef"-ness is *only* relevant for the method in which the parameter is declared. The value of the `thisRobot` variable is still just a reference *value*. Changing the value of that variable later on won't change the *caller's* variable.

Comment: Is there a way to carry the ByRef through, like (C++ has & operator) 

Thanks

Comment: @AidenStrydom: No. You might want to read [Eric Lippert's related blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - changed some code - overloaded the onshow dialog and passed byRef there.

Thanks anyway